# Login error while updating from 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: upgrade, 19.04, 19.10

I was upgrading Ubuntu from 19.04 to 1910, I reckon it was on stage updating softwares. Anyhow, when I come back the screen is black but I see the cursor, I click around and the login screen appears, I sign in only to be informed that something went wrong and I should try again. I do, that, but the result is the same. I'm in a state of panic... What should I do?

The error is:
*"Oops something has gone, wrong problem has occurred and system can't recover, please try logging in again."*

I have tried loggin in three times, will something eventually happen?

Update: thank god I was able to sign via MATE... Maybe I can fix this via, it, but how?

Update:

[image]

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade   
[sudo] password for chiodio:  
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.    
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade  
Reading package lists... Done  
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)   
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.b  
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache   
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a 
dpkg error: dpkg database is locked by another process
```

Edit: I no longer know what to do... When I enter latest recovery mode and use dpkg to fix things, all I get is access partially broken MATE mode. When I reboot, there is no longer ability login in MATE, but lockscreen and when I unlock it, everything freezes.

MATE mode offers me the ability to store everything at least. Im afraid this battle has been lost and I ll have to destroy the partion reinstall whole distro. I really rather not do that, but if there is nothing that can be done...

Comment: @karel, I don't think so... I followed another question and got screenshot from it, for it didn't work.

Comment: Are you using lightdm or GDM ? switching from one to the other by reinstallation might fix your issue of the login screen not appearing

Comment: Lightdm, but I'm not sure if I could even do that... I got into kerner panic, and reversed to previous version, now when I boot and logging everything just freezes...